# Place a custom template in VS 2010 New File dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio template that should appear in the **New File** dialog of Visual Studio 2010. No solution or project needs to be opened in order for my template to appear.
So far I know how to place my template in the **Add New Item** dialog, but can't find info on how to place it in New File dialog.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can add an item that runs a macro, Tools + Customize.  You'll have to write the macro first.  It does however really belong in the Project + Add New Item dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by making my WiX installer put my template (a .mysql file) in a subfolder of my vsix extension folder (which goes a couple of levels below C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions) and then modifyied my **.pkgdef** file to add an entry to the Windows Registry that will specify that same dir as the **TemplatesDir** for this template:

```
[$RootKey$\Projects\{A2FE77E1-B743-11D0-AE1A-00A0C90FFFC3}\AddItemTemplates\TemplateDirs\{79a115c1-b133-4891-9e7b-242509dad272}\/1]
@="#105"
"Package"="{79a115c1-b133-4891-9e7b-242509dad272}"
"TemplatesDir"="$PackageFolder$\\Templates"
"SortPriority"=dword:00000020
```